# Munkres' Topology Chapter 2 Lemma 13.2. Is this description of C in set-builder notation correct?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

This is the statement of Lemma 13.2 in Munkres' Topology Chapter 2.

> Let X be a topological space. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of X such that for each open set U of X and each x in U, there is an element C of $\mathcal{C}$ such that x $\in$C$\subset$U. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for the topology of X.

The English description confuses me. I would like to express the collection $\mathcal{C}$ in set-builder notation. Is what I have written below what the author intends?
Letting $\mathcal{T}$ denote the topology on X:
$$\mathcal{C}=\{V\in\mathcal{T}:\forall U\in\mathcal{T}\forall x\in U\exists C\in\mathcal{C}(x\in C \subset U)\}$$

Is my understanding correct? If not, please explain to me where I may be mistaken.

Comment: Notice that in the set "characteristic property" you are not imposing anything on $V$ (moreover the definition is self referential since you are using the set $\mathcal{C}$ into its own definition). However the  "characteristc property" you've written is the correct formal writing of this lemma's hyphotesis. It's just the rest that is meaningless. Your usage of this set presentation method is very wrong. Think about this for some time. If you still don't understand maybe you should strenghten your set theoretical basics before jumping into topology.

Comment: The author _cannot_ give a definition of $\mathscr C$ in set-builder or any other notation because $\mathscr C$ is not defined. There are many sets that have the properties that $\mathscr C$ does. So anything of the form $\mathscr C=\dots$ is wrong, because $\mathscrC$ could be something else.

Comment: $C$ is **contained in** the set-builder-defined set on the RHS, not equal to it. But yes, the formula you wrote in the set-builder accurately captures the conditions placed on $C$,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble with your suggestion is that this Lemma is not about some well-defined collection $\mathcal C$, it is instead about a certain property of a subcollection $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal T$, i.e. a certain property of a collection $\mathcal C$ of open subsets of $X$.

Without yet stating this property but introducing the notation $\mathcal P(\mathcal C)$ to represent it, what the lemma says is that for any collection $\mathcal C$ of open subsets of $X$, if the property $\mathcal P(\mathcal C)$ is true then $\mathcal C$ is a basis for the topology $\mathcal T$.

The property $\mathcal P(\mathcal C)$ is sort-of what you've written as part of your set builder notation, if you threw away the set builder part. Here's the full statement of the relevant property:
$$\mathcal P(\mathcal C)\,\, := \,\, \forall U\in\mathcal{T}, \forall x\in U, \exists C\in\mathcal{C} \, (x\in C \subset U)
$$

One thing to keep in mind: there can easily be many different sub collections $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal T$ which satisfy the property $\mathcal P(\mathcal C)$, so as I said $\mathcal C$ is not determined by this property.

Just as an example, if $X = \mathbb R^2$, and if $\mathcal T$ is the usual Euclidean topology on $X$, then $\mathcal C = \{\text{all open balls}\}$ satisfies the property $\mathcal P(\mathcal C)$, and $\mathcal C = \{\text{all open squares}\}$ also satisfies it, and many, many other collections $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal T$ satisfy it. As a consequence, by applying the lemma one concludes that there are many many different bases for the Euclidean topology $\mathcal T$ on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: This is extremely clear to me. I was lead to believe by the phrase "$\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open sets of X such that" that what was being described was a well-defined collection. What is actually being described is a **sufficient condition** on some already well-defined collection $\mathcal{C}$. Thanks a lot Lee!